# Send Data to Wampserver Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I made a project which must generate a page on entering message, but it is not working for a reason. I am posting the code below.

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit1"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="Write a message"

        >
                <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

      <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter"
        android:onClick="send"  
          />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.postapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText edit1;
    Button button1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void send(View v)
    {
        String msg  = edit1.getText().toString();
        if(msg.length()>0)
        {           //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "enter length", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                HttpClient httpc = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/demo/server_scripr.php");
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "enter length0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try
                {
                    List<BasicNameValuePair>  vp = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
                    //vp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","01"));
                    vp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",msg));
                    httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(vp));
                    httpc.execute(httpost);
                edit1.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter the field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }


}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.postapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.postapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks, help me in finding the solution

Comment: What is the error? What is the question?

Comment: @doydoy I have posted the question. Can you find error in MainActivity.java because the data is not transported to the localhost

Comment: Replace `localhost` with `10.0.2.2`

Comment: Hey @SunilMishra I tried it still not working! one question why did you mention 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost?

Comment: @Rahul Read this to get information http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely within this line of your code:

```
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/demo/server_scripr.php");
```

Make sure it isn't supposed to be:

> /server_script.php

Comment: No it is server_scripr.php I made

Comment: Are you getting an exception? If so, please add the StackTrace to the original question. There is not enough information here to answer your question.